# Superpower recommendations

Tags: fiction, fantasy

I'm writing a fantasy novel where antagonists have ability to steal skills/abilities from any creature (actually it's more like replacing own skills with others). I need ideas what skills they might steal from different creatures (including mythical ones) besides flight (they already got wings). Please help poor, troubled new user. :D

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. This question is probably better suited for WorldBuilding SE, and I've asked the mods to migrate it there.

Comment: Hi, your question could belong to Worldbuilding but it looks too broad. You have to add more details, including what goals your character is trying to achieve. Questions asking people to give lists of ideas without any criteria to evaluate them are not well received. Take a look at : [How to write a perfect question](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3624/how-to-write-the-perfect-question?cb=1) and [Site tour](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

As far as superpowers are concerned you are limited by your imagination. Extracting the substance dreams are made of, or reading minds, or changing form and appearance, being invisible, being at many places at the same time, time-travelling, controlling the elements fire, water, wind, space, earth could be some of the superpowers that come to my mind. Thank you.